# Authenticating Google Contacts v3 (can't I use my Google Calendar token)?

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I have seen a few topics on this issue but maybe I am overlooking something.

This is my current VB code to authticate for my calendar:

```
Private Function DoAuthentication(ByRef rStrToken As String) As Boolean
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Secrets.ClientId = m_strClientID
    Secrets.ClientSecret = m_strClientSecret
    m_Scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)

    Try
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes,
                                                                 "user", CancellationToken.None,
                                                                 New FileDataStore("xxxxx.Calendar.Application")).Result()

        ' Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "Public Talks And Meeting Schedule Assistant Calendar"
        m_Service = New CalendarService(initializer)

        rStrToken = credential.Token.AccessToken.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' We encountered some kind of problem, perhaps they have not yet authenticated?
        ' Can we isolate that as the exception?
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

I now also want to work with the Google Contact data. So I modified the above method to include this scope:

```
m_Scopes.Add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/")
```

Then I tried to use it:

```
If (DoAuthentication(strToken)) Then
    Dim settings As New RequestSettings("xx", strToken)
    settings.AutoPaging = True
    iResult = RESULT_SUCCESS_OAUTH
    m_ContactsRequest = New ContactsRequest(settings)
    Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = m_ContactsRequest.GetContacts()

    For Each oContact As Contact In f.Entries
        Console.WriteLine(oContact.Name.ToString)
    Next
Else
    Return RESULT_FAILED_OAUTH
End If
```

But it raises an exception: 401 Unauthorized.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I found this webpage: http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/

So I tried to implement some of it:

Private Function DoAuthentication(ByRef rStrToken As String, ByRef rParameters As OAuth2Parameters) As Boolean
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Secrets.ClientId = m_strClientID
    Secrets.ClientSecret = m_strClientSecret
    m_Scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
    m_Scopes.Add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/")

```
Try
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes,
                                                             "user", CancellationToken.None,
                                                             New FileDataStore("xx.Calendar.Application")).Result()

    ' Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
    Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
    initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
    initializer.ApplicationName = "Public Talks And Meeting Schedule Assistant Calendar"
    m_Service = New CalendarService(initializer)

    rStrToken = credential.Token.AccessToken.ToString()
    rParameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken
    rParameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken
Catch ex As Exception
    ' We encountered some kind of problem, perhaps they have not yet authenticated?
    ' Can we isolate that as the exception?
    Return False
End Try
```

And the code:

```
   Dim parameters As New OAuth2Parameters
    If (DoAuthentication(strToken, parameters)) Then
        Dim settings As New RequestSettings("GoogleCalIF", parameters)
        settings.AutoPaging = True
        iResult = RESULT_SUCCESS_OAUTH
        m_ContactsRequest = New ContactsRequest(settings)
        Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = m_ContactsRequest.GetContacts()

        For Each oContact As Contact In f.Entries
            Console.WriteLine(oContact.Name.ToString)
        Next
    Else
        Return RESULT_FAILED_OAUTH
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

But I still get a 401 Exception. I have correctly added the Contacts API to my Google Console. Confused.

I am afraid I have a headache. I can't get past this 401 Unathorized issue.

Comment: It seems that I have to revoke the current connection to my Google account and then authenticate again so that it would do both services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! There were a few things that I had to do.

**Step 1**

It seems that I needed by scopes to be one line string with a space in between. So I changed my authentication method to:

```
Private Function DoAuthentication(ByRef rStrToken As String, ByRef rParameters As OAuth2Parameters) As Boolean

    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Secrets.ClientId = m_strClientID
    Secrets.ClientSecret = m_strClientSecret
    m_Scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/")

    Try
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes,
                 "user", CancellationToken.None,
                 New FileDataStore("PublicTalkSoftware.Calendar.Application")).Result()

        ' Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "Public Talks And Meeting Schedule Assistant Calendar"
        m_Service = New CalendarService(initializer)

        rStrToken = credential.Token.AccessToken.ToString()
        rParameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken
        rParameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' We encountered some kind of problem, perhaps they have not yet authenticated?
        ' Can we isolate that as the exception?
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

I commented out the line **CalendarService.Scope.Calendar** and used the literal text. Not sure if that was the best thing to do.

**Step 2**

In the aforementioned method I passed in a **OAuth2Parameters** object and populated a couple of entries.

**Step 3**

The calling code is something like this:

```
Dim m_ContactsRequest As ContactsRequest
Dim strToken As String = ""
Dim iResult As Integer = 0
Dim parameters As New OAuth2Parameters
If (DoAuthentication(strToken, parameters)) Then
   iResult = RESULT_SUCCESS_OAUTH
Else
   Return RESULT_FAILED_OAUTH
End If

Try
   Dim settings As New RequestSettings("XX", parameters)
   m_ContactsRequest = New ContactsRequest(settings)
   Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = m_ContactsRequest.GetContacts()

   For Each oContact As Contact In f.Entries
         Console.WriteLine(oContact.Name.FullName.ToString)
   Next
Catch ex As Exception
    ' We encountered some kind of problem, perhaps they have not yet authenticated?
    ' Can we isolate that as the exception?
    Return False
End Try
```

**Step 4**

Since I already had an access token on the PC, I had to **revoke** it, so that I would also get access to the contacts as opposed to just the calendar service.